# A/B test subscription pricing and free trial effects

Tags: android, google-play-services, subscription, ab-testing

We want to launch a new subscription product and be able to decide impact of free trial vs not and also couple different price options.

For one IAP we would just create different skus and based of abtest bucket send the right sku. For subscription the IAP is auto renewed thus moving users from one bucket to another feels lot of friction.
Also for understanding effects of free trial vs not doing it using one sku and in linear fashion seems to be better.

What approaches have AD developers used for their subscription features?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about **marketing strategies**, not about **programming**

Comment: For me this is related to programming, since there may be some Apis, setting around Playstore, that I may not be aware of that can help achieve this. Sure if you feel its not related to programming and have pointer for right platform send my way.

Comment: `For me this is related to programming ...` I see no code, though. Where is your effort? Are you asking for a tutorial, resources, ideas, recommendations,  or whatever? Again, it's off-topic, on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we do in our case.

We offer 2 SKU, with same pricing and same charging period. The differences is, one is with N days free trial enabled, another is without free trial enabled.

[image]

Then, we have 2 buttons in our purchase dialog. Green is dedicated to SKU with free-trial. Orange color is dedicated to SKU without free-trial.

Of course, you may also choose to use Firebase remote config, to decide whether to show/ hide the free trial button, based on your business strategy.

Comment: Thanks. Thought of this as one solution. Since playstore allows to set and unset 'Free Trial' my intution is Playstore doesn't recommend creating two skus.